# How do i calculate the average cpi?

Tags: performance, cpu-speed

Im kinda stuck on some work. To find the the cpi i would need to multiply the percentage of instructions with the clock cycle but what is shown is avg stall cycles. I don't really understand how to approach this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

A computer with a 5 stage pipeline is measured and has the following characteristics

Instruction Type  % of instructions.   Avg. stall cycles/instructions

Branches             .3                               .7

Loads & Stores       .2                               .2

ALU ops              .4                               0

Other                .1                               .2

a) what is the average CPI for the computer?

b) What is the speedup for this machine?

Comment: So, what have **you** done?

Comment: So far I multiplied the percentage of instructions with avg stall cycles and then added them up, but don't think its right.                                                                      .3 * .7 = .21  
.2 * .2 = .04  
.4 *  0 = 0  
.1 * .2 = .02  
          .27

Comment: You just put in some * and /, but is there any logic or reason to that?

Comment: (.3 * .7) + (.2 * .2) + (.4 * 0) + (.1 * .2) = .27 avg cpi

Answer (score 0):

In your last comment, you have the correct weighted average of *stall* cycles per instruction. But you need the total cycles per instruction presumably.

As for speedup, it's unclear what your baseline is.